# Dimension of a real vector space defined below

Tags: real-analysis

The dimension of the real vector space
$ V = \{f : (−1, 1) → R | f $ is infinitely differentiable on $(−1, 1)$ and $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n ≥ 0\}$ is-

$(a)$ Infinite

$(b)$ Finite

$(c)$ 1

Any hint to solve the problem would help. I couldn't formulate such function.

Comment: These are [smooth but not analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function), and there are *many*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For $P(x)$ a polynomial in $x$ with real coefficients, we have $P(e^{-\frac1{x^2}})\in V$.